# How to print a recursive trace (factorial function)?

Tags: javascript, recursion

In the interest of better understanding recursion, I'm trying to figure out how to log a recursive trace to the console.  I've got the 'trace down' part, but I'm not sure how to 'bubble up' the solution.  Any suggestions for a perfectly placed console.log statement?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
function factorial (num) {
    if (num === 1) {
        console.log('factorial(' + num + ') = ' + num);
        return 1;
    } else {
        console.log('factorial(' + num + ') = ' + num + ' * ' + 'factorial(' + (num - 1) + ')');
        return num * factorial(num - 1);
    }
}
```

which prints the following to the console:

```
factorial(5) = 5 * factorial(4)
factorial(4) = 4 * factorial(3)
factorial(3) = 3 * factorial(2)
factorial(2) = 2 * factorial(1)
factorial(1) = 1
120
```

But what about the 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 part?  I know it's happening in there somewhere, how can I print it?

I guess I'd expect it to look something like this:

```
1
1 * 2
2 * 3
6 * 4
24 * 5
120
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Ok after more searching I found this over at [CodeRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/491023/java/java/trace-recursion-questions#2877086), unfortunately sans code (and written in Java):

```
Enter fact(6)  
    Enter fact(5)  
        Enter fact(4)  
            Enter fact(3)  
                Enter fact(2)  
                    Enter fact(1)  
                        Enter fact(0)  
                        0!Ret: 1  
                    Ret: 1 * fact(n-1) = 1 * fact(0) = 1 * 1 = 1  
                Ret: 2 * fact(n-1) = 2 * fact(1) = 2 * 1 = 2  
            Ret: 3 * fact(n-1) = 3 * fact(2) = 3 * 2 = 6  
        Ret: 4 * fact(n-1) = 4 * fact(3) = 4 * 6 = 24  
    Ret: 5 * fact(n-1) = 5 * fact(4) = 5 * 24 = 120  
Ret: 6 * fact(n-1) = 6 * fact(5) = 6 * 120 = 720  
fact(6) = 720
```

Pretty cool, right?  After more experimenting, I still can't achieve this though...

Comment: Can you post an example of the output you expect? Also you can simply log factorial out of the statement, once.

Comment: Just added my expected output :)

Comment: Find the answer, which i have mentioned.
It should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
function factorial (num) {
    if (num === 1) {
        console.log(num); //print new line after this
        return 1;
    } else {
        var val = factorial(num - 1);
        console.log(num +'*' + val);  //print new line after this
        return num * val;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely getting closer!  But I want to capture the entire trace, not just the last one...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best explained by using your example (edited a little) with comments. Assume you call this function with the parameter set to **5** the first time.

```
// num = 5, the first time it's called
function factorial (num) {
    console.log('factorial(' + num + ')');

    if (num === 1) {
        // If num === 1, the function will just return 1 and exit.
        return 1;
    } else {
        // Otherwise, which happens almost every time (since 1 is only
        // reached once and then it stops). For 5, this would return
        // 5 * factorial(4), which in order returns 4 * factorial(3),
        // and so on.
        return num * factorial(num - 1);
    }
}
```

This output might help you understand:

```
factorial(5) == (5) * (factorial(4)) // (5) * (4 * 3 * 2 * 1)
factorial(4) == (4) * (factorial(3)) // (4) * (3 * 2 * 1)
factorial(3) == (3) * (factorial(2)) // (3) * (2 * 1)
factorial(2) == (2) * (factorial(1)) // (2) * (1)
factorial(1) == (1)                  // (1)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm still confused... the // stuff on the right -> that's all happening inside the function, right?  So shouldn't there be a way to log it exactly as you've typed it?

Comment: @i_made_that No, not exactly, since in the first row, I only know the `5` and that `4 * 3 * 2 * 1` part is calculated in factorial(4). I'll edit it a little to make it more clear.

Comment: Yeah this is what has me scratching my head :)  When we reach the last row (factorial(1) == 1), factorial has to then pass the computed values BACK up through the nested functions doesn't it?  In my imaginary world I could capture this with a cleverly-positioned console.log...

Comment: @Broxzier It would be better to use the condition `num <= 1` in `if` statement cause it allows to return factorial of 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
function factorial (num) {
        for (var i=1; i<6-num; i++)
            console.log('    ');
        }
        console.log('Enter fact('+num+')'); //add code to move new line
        if(num==0) {
            for (var i=1; i<6-num; i++)
                console.log('    ');
            }
            console.log('0!Ret: 1 '); // add code to move new line
            return 1;
        } else {
            int val = factorial(num-1);
            for (var i=1; i<6-num; i++)
                console.log('    ');
            }
            console.log('Ret:'+num+ ' * fact(n-1) = ' + num+ ' * fact('+(num-1)+') = '+num+' * ' + val + ' = ' + (num*val) ); // add code to move new line
            return num*val;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be better to collapse your two answers into one.